# Product across inequalities

Tags: inequality

Suppose I have a sequence of numbers $\{a_i \}_{i=1}^{N}$ and $\{b_i \}_{i=1}^{N}$ with $0\leq a_i\leq 1$ and $0 \leq b_i \leq 1$ for $i=1,...,N$. Is stating

**If $a_i \leq b_i$ $\forall i$ then $\prod_{i=1}^{N}a_i \leq \prod_{i=1}^{N} b_i$**

correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: A simple geometric interpretation of the $n=3$ case: If the length, width, and height of a rectangular box are each smaller than those of another box, then the first box must occupy less volume than the second. On a more formal note, try to convince yourself that you could've assumed that $b_i=1$ for all $i$ without any loss of generality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct. You can show it by induction.

For $N=1$, it's obvious.

Suppose that for $N(\ge 1),0\le \prod_{i=1}^{N}a_i\le\prod_{i=1}^{N}b_i$ holds. Then, since $0\le a_{N+1}\le b_{N+1}$, we have
$$\begin{align}\prod_{i=1}^{N+1}b_i-\prod_{i=1}^{N+1}a_i&=b_{N+1}\prod_{i=1}^{N}b_i-a_{N+1}\prod_{i=1}^{N}a_i\\&\ge b_{N+1}\prod_{i=1}^{N}a_i-a_{N+1}\prod_{i=1}^{N}a_i\\&=(b_{N+1}-a_{N+1})\prod_{i=1}^{N}a_i\\&\ge 0.\end{align}$$
So it holds for $N+1$.

Therefore, we know that it holds for any $N\in\mathbb N$. **Q.E.D.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your inequality is correct. Think about it this way: if you have two numbers that are both smaller than two other numbers and you multiply both pairs together the product of the smaller pair will certainly be less than the product of the larger pair, correct?